# Jenkins and Maven Integration: Environment Variables are NULL

Tags: maven, variables, jenkins, continuous-integration, environment

I am trying to inject environment variable in the Maven build process so that I can use them in my test scripts for various purposes.

Below is my Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.46.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <environmentVariables>
           <jenkins.package>${env.V_PACKAGE}</jenkins.package>
           <jenkins.release>${env.V_RELEASE}</jenkins.release>
       </environmentVariables>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

With in my test scripts I am trying to read these build parameters but I am getting all null values, can you please help me how to get this fixed?

In the test scripts

```
String VANSAH_PACKAGE=System.getProperty("jenkins.package");
String VANSAH_RELEASE=System.getProperty("jenkins.release");
System.out.println(" V_PACKAGE :" + V_PACKAGE);
System.out.println(" V_RELEASE :" + V_RELEASE);
```

My Jenkins String Parameters are

```
V_PACKAGE
V_RELEASE
```

Comment: Please don't mark any of your Stack Overflow questions as urgent - volunteers will answer at their leisure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should be using http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables instead

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit I am new to Maven, I have been using all these days.

Comment: Sorted out, Thank you Robert.

Comment: @Prashanna: don't forget to accept this answer, if it was the solution. To accept an answer, click on the tick mark to the left, so it turns green. This is how we thanks contributors for their efforts here.